# How can one invoke a keyboard shortcut from within an AppleScript?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I need to invoke a keyboard shortcut from within an AppleScript code, later to be used as a startup item (i.e. the alternative to having to press something at every log in).

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can do :

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using command down
    keystroke "v" using {option down, command down}
end tell
```

To press : <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression that what you're trying to do is a copy command (i.e., <kbd>⌘C</kbd>)—am I right?

Here's an example from one of my scripts:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Microsoft Entourage" to activate
    tell menu "Edit" of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1 of process "Microsoft Entourage"
        click menu item "Select All"
        click menu item "Copy"
    end tell
    key code 123
end tell
```

That is, I script the menu command instead of scripting shortcuts.

You might also take a look and see if you have `/Library/Scripts/UI Element Scripts/Key Down-Up.applescript`, which should give you alternate ideas of how to emulate keyboard actions.

And of course, there are a lot of examples in `/Library/Scripts/` and `~/Library/Scripts/`, many of which are worth a look in general.