# How can I use a keyboard shortcut to run two or more keyboard shortcuts

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I'm using Due app on the mac, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have one keyboard shortcut to run the app, reset the running timer ( command+ shift+ s) and then run the timer again (command + S)
is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Keyboard Maestro should do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Write an AppleScript that launches your shortcut(s), then assign a shortcut to that AppleScript.**

These two steps have been asked/answered on here previously.  See:

- [How can one invoke a keyboard shortcut from within an AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/how-can-one-invoke-a-keyboard-shortcut-from-within-an-applescript)
- [How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript I wrote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote)

It's probably a better idea to write the AppleScript to do exactly what you want it to do rather than just execute shortcuts, but the option is there.